# Ambiguous usage of "got"

Tags: idioms

I read this sentence:

> I'm glad I got to know her.

"*Got*" can be used like permission, like "*I was allowed/able to*", but it can also be used like the ongoing status of something, as in

> When I got to this point in my life…

Which is it in this case?

Comment: What exactly is the difference between the two meanings in this case? I don't see the distinction here.

Comment: There is a distinction to me, I thought I made it clear, sorry. I'll try again:

I got to go to the park.
I got to the park.

These are two very different sentiments in my mind, are they not in yours?

Comment: The distinction is essentially modal. One sense is that of 'being allowed to' ('allowed' at least by circumstances, if not by official permission). The other is _get_ as the inchoative of _be_, i.e, 'come to be' or _become_; that's the sense behind _when I got to that point_.

Comment: @ user43217: That "obligation" sense is a *third* meaning to *"got"*, which is usually part of the "phrasal verb" *to have got to*. It's generally considered "sub-standard" to omit "have", so in you example, you could grammatically (if somewhat awkwardly) say *"I'm glad I **have** got to get to know her"* (meaning *I'm glad I'm obliged to get to know her*).

Answer (score 1):

Without more context it's impossible to say exactly what nuance is intended in OP's example.

To *get to* [do something] can mean *have the chance to* do it.

To *get to know* someone/something can mean *become [very well] acquainted* with them/it.

So OP might mean he's glad he came to *know her [well]*, or glad he *had the chance to* know her.

---

You might think it's stylistically awkward to use [both senses consecutively](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22motor%20hummed%20away%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22get%20to%20get%20acquainted%22&oq=%22get%20to%20get%20acquainted%22&gs_l=serp.3...14875.15267.3.15727.2.2.0.0.0.0.61.110.2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.IX3IAGrTONk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45645796,d.d2k&fp=9d9b30455b6c0f23&biw=1271&bih=922), but there's nothing grammatically incorrect about...

> *The NAFEC duty was boring most of the time, but gave me a good chance [to get to get](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HYgC7dH7sDgC&pg=PA100&dq=%22get%20to%20get%20acquainted%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bkd5UdyMDInT0QXljYCABg&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22get%20to%20get%20acquainted%22&f=false) acquainted with the crews*.

---

There are many other meanings for *to get*, including *have got to = must, should, are obliged to*...

> *"I've [got to get to](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22motor%20hummed%20away%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22got%20to%20get%20to%20know%22&oq=%22got%20to%20get%20to%20know%22&gs_l=serp.3...3197.8348.0.8739.19.15.0.0.0.3.250.1299.13j1j1.15.0...0.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.7uXUy0yRS_A&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=9d9b30455b6c0f23&biw=1271&bih=922) know her""* (I'm compelled, or I really want to get to know her).

...and to *get = become, arrive at a point where, reach a state of*...

> ...he saw more and more of her every day, until he [got to be](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JGQ4AAAAIAAJ&q=%22he%20got%20to%20be%20restless%22&dq=%22he%20got%20to%20be%20restless%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=C0x5UbmWKoLa0QWH1ICAAw&ved=0CDIQ6AEwADgK) restless and nervous when he was not with her.

Answer (score 0):

It's a third sense, one of enjoying an opportunity or ability for something-- the third intransitive sense, according to Merriam-Webster,  [out of at least 19](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get):

> **3 a** : to be able [never *got* to go to college]

Comment: Yes, that's the modal sense.